# how to allow all content in CKEDITOR custom build , i want to make inline styling but it is not authorized

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckeditor4.x

this is my ckeditor.js file

```
import ClassicEditorBase from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';

import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';

//..

export default class ClassicEditor extends ClassicEditorBase {}

// Plugins to include in the build.
ClassicEditor.builtinPlugins = [
    Essentials,
    UploadAdapter,
    Autoformat,
    Bold,
    //..
    
  PluginProcedure,
  InsertTable
];

// Editor configuration.
ClassicEditor.defaultConfig = {

    toolbar: {
        items: [
            'heading',
            '|',
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'link',
      'table',
      'essentials',
      'procedurePlugin',
      'insertTable'

        ]
    },
    image: {
        toolbar: [
            'imageStyle:inline',
            'imageStyle:block',
            'imageStyle:side',
            '|',
            'toggleImageCaption',
            'imageTextAlternative'
        ]
    },
    table: {
        contentToolbar: [
            'tableColumn',
            'tableRow',
            'mergeTableCells'
        ]
    },

    // This value must be kept in sync with the language defined in webpack.config.js.
    language: 'en'
};
```

i want to add inline css in my custom plugin using setData()
but inline styling or classes not works

this is my plugin code :

```
import Plugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/plugin';
import ButtonView from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/src/button/buttonview';
import { getPosition, insertData } from './utils';

import TableIcon from './icons/table-icon.svg';
import { data } from './data-procedure';



export default class PluginProcedure extends Plugin {
    init() {
        const editor = this.editor;

        editor.ui.componentFactory.add( 'procedurePlugin', locale => {
            const view = new ButtonView( locale );

            view.set( {
                label: 'Procédure prélèvements ',
                withText: false,
                tooltip: true,
                icon: TableIcon
            } );

            // Callback executed once the image is clicked.
            view.on( 'execute', () => {


                editor.model.change( writer => {

                    editor.setData(" <h1 style="color:red"> <h1>")
                    //not works


                } );
            } );

            return view;
        } );
    }

}
```

i google it and i find that require a configuration to allow content

```
  allowedContent: true
extraAllowedContent: "* [*]",
```

it still not works because  i don't know how to add configuration rules ,
i work on custom build , please help !
or if there is exemples .

Answer (score -1):

```
htmlSupport:  { allow: [
        {
            name: 'iframe',
            attributes: true,
            classes: true,
            styles: true
        }
    ]},
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.